# IntelliJ IDEA, Community or Ultimate version?

Tags: scala, licensing, intellij-idea

From the Scala perspective, is there any advantage missed by using the Community version of IDEA over the Ultimate version.

I've checked the version comparison chart provided and don't really require many of the features and integrations specified. I'd be interested in things like the mentioned code coverage support, but suspect that it would be Java centric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coverage support is available for Scala in the Ultimate Edition. Otherwise, from the Scala perspective, functionality is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is the coverage support documented somewhere?

Comment: It works the same as for Java, check help, however there is a known limitation, coverage results are not displayed in the editor yet, only in the project view, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-2065.

Comment: Actually they have close the issue in the beginning of december.